# Select option - Alert

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

```
<!-- Select Basic -->
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5">
<span class="input-group-addon"> Language / اللغة / زبان </span>
    <select id="language" name="language" class="form-control" required>   
      <option selected="true" style="text-align:center;" disabled="disabled">Select a language</option>    
        <option value=2><?php echo lang_content(23, 1);?></option>
        <option value=1><?php echo lang_content(24, 1);?></option>
        <option value=3><?php echo lang_content(25, 3);?></option>

     </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have language dropdown, but when I click submit without selecting an option, it just show a loading icon and doesn't move further.

I have to trigger an alert, if the user doesn't select an option.
How can I do that?

Comment: there's no JS here to support the "alert". Nor any other PHP. So it's a "show me how". You also tagged as sql, why?

Comment: first of all put all values in "" like value="1" or value="2" and then try it

Comment: I don't really know, how to add that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the select in `<form>` tag and `select` `required` will work
Check on fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/7qbn7aex/)

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5">
<span class="input-group-addon"> Language / اللغة / زبان </span>
<form >
    <select id="language" name="language" class="form-control" required>   
      <option selected="true" style="text-align:center;" disabled="disabled">Select a language</option>    
        <option value=2>lang1</option>
        <option value=1>lang2</option>
        <option value=3>lang3</option>

     </select>
     <input type="submit">
     </form>
  </div>
</div>
```